# regex excluding time from text

Tags: regex, selenium, replaceall

I would like to extract time from the text below using regex.

Text: "Media: a few minutes ago, 3:25 pm uts"

Regex pattern to select only time (ex: 3:25) from the above text?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the text you want to extract from your example?

Comment: I need to extract time 3:25 only and remove the rest of the text.

Comment: What about am vs pm? Please update your question with details so that we can help effectively.

Comment: updated. I need only to be able to print time ex: 3:25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex `/\b[0-9]+:[0-9]+\b/`. Explanation:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `:` - literal colon
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `\b` - word boundary

I do not know your specific use in selenium, but here is an example:

```
src = 'Media: a few minutes ago, 3:25 pm uts'
pattern = re.compile(r'(\\b[0-9]+:[0-9]+\\b)')
match = pattern.search(src)
print match.groups()[0]
```

Output:

```
3:25
```